# Use Enzyme in Jest test to find a name-spaced child component in React

Tags: javascript, namespaces, jestjs, react-bootstrap, enzyme

I am building a component using some `react-bootstrap` components, specifically `Modal` and its name-spaced children, e.g. `Modal.Heading` (or `Modal.Title`, `Modal.Body`, etc.). For example:

```
...
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap/lib';
import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal>
          <p>{someContent}</p>
          <OtherComponent/>
          <Modal.Header>{someOtherContent}</Modal.Header>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using Enzyme within a Jest test suite I can find various children of the `Modal` component including DOM elements and other custom React components. However I can't find name-spaced child components:

```
const modal = shallow(<MyComponent/>).find('Modal');

it('should find the Modal element', () => {
  expect(modal).toHaveLength(1); // passes
});

it('should find a child DOM element', () => {
  expect(modal.find('p')).toHaveLength(1); // passes
});

it('should find a regular child component', () => {
  expect(modal.find('OtherComponent')).toHaveLength(1); // passes
});

it('should find a name-spaced child component', () => {
  expect(modal.find('Modal.Header')).toHaveLength(1); // fails *****
});
```

I have tried:

- `.find('Modal.Header')`, i.e. including the namespace, as shown above
- `.find('Header')`, i.e. leaving off the namespace,
- `mount(<MyComponent/>)` instead of `shallow(<MyComponent/>)` in combination with both of the above `find` options

So how do I use Enzyme to find a name-spaced child component?

Answer (score 4):

A non-name-spaced component can be identified as a parameter for the `find` method as either a variable (e.g. `OtherComponent`) *or* a string (e.g. `'OtherComponent'`) but a name-spaced component can only be identified as a variable (e.g. `Namespace.Component`) but *not* as a string (e.g. not as `'Namespace.Component'`). i.e.:

```
it('should find a non-name-spaced component as a variable', () => {
  expect(modal.find(OtherComponent)).toHaveLength(1); // passes
});

it('should find a non-name-spaced component as a string', () => {
  expect(modal.find('OtherComponent')).toHaveLength(1); // passes
});

it('should find a name-spaced component as a variable', () => {
  expect(modal.find(Modal.Heading)).toHaveLength(1); // passes
});

it('should (not) find a name-spaced component as a string', () => {
  expect(modal.find('Modal.Heading')).toHaveLength(1); // fails
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I found mine by using 'ModalHeader' or 'ModalTitle' in the find function. So I had `expect(modal.find('ModalTitle')).toBe(true);`

I found this out by chance when it showed in the console what object was being passed to expect. This was the output:

```
Expected value to have length:
  1
Received:      {"complexSelector": {"buildPredicate": [Function buildPredicate], "childrenOfNode": [Function childrenOfNode], "findWhereUnwrapped": [Function findWhereUnwrapped]}, "length": 0, "node": undefined, "nodes": Array [], "options": {}, "renderer": null, "root": {"complexSelector": {"buildPredicate": [Function buildPredicate], "childrenOfNode": [Function childrenOfNode], "findWhereUnwrapped": [Function findWhereUnwrapped]}, "length": 1, "node": <div className="static-modal"><Modal animation={true} autoFocus={true} backdrop={true} bsClass="modal" className="modal" dialogComponentClass={[Function ModalDialog]} enforceFocus={true} keyboard={true} manager={{"add": [Function anonymous], "containers": Array [],"data": Array [], "handleContainerOverflow": true, "hideSiblingNodes": true, "isTopModal": [Function anonymous], "modals": Array [], "remove":[Function anonymous]}} onHide={[Function onHide]} renderBackdrop={[Function renderBackdrop]} restoreFocus={true} show={false}>**<ModalHeader bsClass="modal-header" closeButton={false} closeLabel="Close">**
```

I was looking through it and I saw the ModalHeader and I knew thats what I had to look for. For it to display the object I had to use `toHaveLength(1)`, it doesn't show when it was .exists()).toBe(true), and I had to `.find('Modal')` on my component first before I called expect(modal.find()) on the variable. So I had;

`let modal = shallow(<ModalInstance title={props.title.delete}/>)`
first and then from reading this post I saw you had
`let modal = shallow(<ModalInstance title={props.title.delete}/>).find('Modal')` and when I called `expect(modal.find('Title')).toHaveLength(1)`, that's when it showed the error message.